# Multiple markers on this line when using @Transactional

Tags: spring, markers, transactional

for example:

```
@Transactional 
public boolean addPersonToDb(Person p) { // message on this line
 //some logic
}
```

Code compiles and runs with no problems.

Message itself: Multiple markers at this line

- implements

com.pname1.pname2.pname3.pname4.PersonDAO.addPersonToDb

- advised by

org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation)

I can't really understand if it is an error or just a message, looking at other threads people get that as an error. I am just worrying if my transactions work.

Ok, the class implements interface and its method annotated as transactional , anything wrong with that?

**Update: solved some minor errors, web app works but I still get that message(not in stack trace, but on the line breakpoint):**

**advised by 
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation)**

Current situation:

```
        @Transactional
   public void registerNewUser(Person p) { // this gives message on line breakpoint - advised by ...; AND this method is implemented by interface

    pd.addPersonToDb(p);


}

@Transactional
public void blabla(Person p){ // this does not, as expected; AND it is not in interface

}
```

Do my transactions work or not? (I have no exceptions and web application runs and the methods work)

I can't understand if this message error or not?

Comment: It is OK. to make a method implementation transactional, even if the implemented method is not transactional itself. Which means the problem lies elsewhere. can you paste the complete stack trace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with multiple markers is not a problem at all; it's purely informational. (The method is part of the implementation of an interface or abstract method, which you probably already knew, *and* it is intercepted by AOP because of the `@Transactional` annotation. I hope this doesn't surprise you…)

The error is because the class you are annotating doesn't implement a suitable interface (or interfaces), which would be necessary to use the built-in JDK proxy mechanism to put the AOP interceptors in place in the bean. (Bean-level interceptors are done through a proxy object that applies the transactional behavior and then delegates to the real object.) The JDK proxy mechanism only works with interfaces; intercepting anything else requires a different approach.

The two possible fixes for this are:

1. Make the bean class implement a suitable interface that has *all* the methods of your class that are marked as `@Transactional`.
2. Add cglib as a dependency, which Spring uses to dynamically write the classes that do the interception. (This is clever stuff.)

You only need to use one of these fixes, and the second one is *very easy* if you're using a build system like Maven; just update the dependencies. (Also, avoid doing calls to intercepted methods via `this`, whether explicit or not. That side-steps the AOP interception.)

Comment: I use maven, I added cglib, but now whenever I try to annotate interface implemented methods in implementation class I get this advised by, HOWEVER when I use transactional on other methods (not specified in interface that is implemented) everything works fine. Why I can't annotate methods implemented by interface?

Comment: I have no idea what's wrong, but I know for sure that when I do that sort of thing it works just fine for me. I include CGLIB in my dependencies and let Spring work it all out…

Comment: I must admit your description is difficult for me, so this message can be or cannot be? Now I don't have any exception only this message on line breakpoint. Please see updated answer :-)

Comment: there is no need to have @Transactional at the implemented methods. this code will work as it is, provided everything else is correct.

Comment: Neither of both solutions works for me. Any other ideas how to get rid of this "Around Advice Markers" warnings?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same red markers next to method signature with `@Transactional` annotation above.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void updateBook(Book book) {
    bookDao.updateBook(book);
}
```

The message of such markers was as following

> Multiple markers at this line
>       - implements bookmanager.service.BookService.updateBook
>       - advised by 
>        org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation)

My fix is that I replaced this annotation `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` with the following annotation `@javax.transaction.Transactional`.

I use *Hibernate framework* to manage transactions in my app.

Hope it will help you too.

Answer (score 1):

Your transactions will work, provided everything else is correct. "Advised by" here is purely informational and shows that your method is advised by spring's TransactionInterceptor.invoke method.

About multiple marker problem, it shows up when you implement something, because there are two informations: first is "advised by", and second that this method is implementing something.

If you are unsure, I suggest that you write an integration test and test the changes in the database. But you do not have to do anything else, your code will work as it is. (If, as I stated before, everything else is correct.)

Comment: Thanks, please don't downvote previous answer, it is correct I had an error before which was solved and this is my plain stupid confusion. When something pop-ups for first time like these advice markers, it gets me crazy ( control freak) :-)